# Signing with DSS Desktop App (Digital Signature Service)

Tags: java

I am trying to sign a PDF document with DSS Desktop Standlone App, and my problem is that I cannot use this application in MacOS environnement due to MSCAPI.

There is a solution for MacOs ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to sign using PKCS11 option, by providing the file to driver related to the smartcard/USB token you use.

Also you may try to sign using the [online version](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/home) and [Nexu](https://github.com/nowina-solutions/nexu) application. I work for the company that develops Nexu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Hello, the link here leads to the official eSignature creation/validation tool of European Commission. Nexu is an open-source project, used for signing on the same online tool provided by European Commission.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the project is open-source, or not, you still need to disclose affiliation when mentioning the project. The disclosure doesn't have to be formal, just a simple "... this project is developed by the company I work for" or something to that effect is sufficient.

Comment: The question has been originally asked about DSS, only it was about its standalone version, while I have provided a link to its web version, so I did not think it is required to specify my affiliation to the project. But ok, it is well noted.